# Make 8x8 chess board using termui grid

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I need to create grid 8*8 using gizak/termui package in GoLang and fill it with some runes so I could put there any one later.
I've learned source code of this package so I tried to do so:

```
grid := ui.NewGrid()
grid.SetRect(screenWidth/2-30, screenHeight/2-8, screenWidth/2+30, screenHeight/2+8)

var rows []interface{}
for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
    var cols []interface{}
    for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
        cols = append(cols, ui.NewCol(1.0/8, "t"))

    }
    rows = append(rows, ui.NewRow(1.0/8, "P"))
}
grid.Set(rows...)
```

but I get some type mathcing errors like panic: InterfaceSlice() given a non-slice type
Help me please to make 8*8 grid any working way

Answer (score 1):

You need put a widget or a row or column to second parameter of `ui.NewRow` or `ui.NewCol`, otherwise you get error while setting rows/columns to grid. Also usage of `ui.NewCol` or `ui.NewRow` a bit different than you did as i saw in this example grid usage [Grid Example](https://github.com/gizak/termui/blob/master/_examples/grid.go).

And this is the code to make 8*8 grid with some texts assigned.

```
    grid := ui.NewGrid()
    grid.SetRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    var gridDone []interface{}
    
    p := widgets.NewParagraph()
    p.Text = "P"
        
    t := widgets.NewParagraph()
    t.Text = "t"
        
    temp := t
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
      
      if i ==  0 {
        t = p
      } else if i == 1 {
        t = temp
      }
      
      gridDone = append(gridDone, ui.NewRow(1.0/8,
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, p),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ui.NewCol(1.0/8, t),
            ),
        )
    }
    
    grid.Set(gridDone...)
```

Comment: That's working, but only when we set the size of grid to full-screen can I do another size? Like in my code fragment in the question?